# extract characters from Buffer and store it

Tags: c++, string, sockets, buffer

I am a bit confused with extracting digits from buffers. Could you please help?

I m using C++.

I have a buffer from which I want to **extract** some **digits only and store them in a variable**. What's the best way to do that? Please check that socket programming is used.

```
char Buffer[1024];
bool bContinue = TRUE;

while (bContinue) {
                memset(Buffer, 0, 1024);

                int iLengthReceived = recv(LocalSocket,
                    (char *)Buffer,
                    1024,
                    0);

                switch (iLengthReceived) {
                case 0: 
                    //something
                    break;

                case socket_ERROR:
                    //something
                    break;

                default:
                    printf("%s", Buffer);
 }
}
```

For example if I print the buffer: `printf("%s", Buffer);`  I get : [0K 4095 31]

Now from that I need to get only the 4095 and store it in a variable.

I thought to convert to string so I used : `string str=string(Buffer);`
But if I print it: `printf("%s",str);` I get NULL .
What am I doing wrong and what's the easiest way to do this? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT: Solved**, I forgot by mistake to set a condition bContinue=false at the default mode, thus it never went out of the loop.

Comment: That should be

    `printf("%*.s", iLengthReceived, Buffer);`

Comment: @EJP - and even then, that discounts the possibility of a `'\0'` character in the midst of the *non*-string of data.

Comment: "I m using C++." But why did you tag it as C then? -> I switched the tags

Comment: I thought I tagged as c++, I m sorry, probably by writing fast. I tried the command as EJP suggested but I don't read anything at my console right now. Any other way?The problem is that this way we print one by one all the characters of the buffer which is filled dynamically. I saw that it sends 9, 19, then 10 characters...many routines running at the back. I thought to somehow isolate some digits by pointer but still it doesnt work.

Comment: Hello, my question remains, how can I store the buffer and convert it to string ? If I have a string I know how to find the word I m looking for, the problem is to get the string. Thank you !